# Objection Framework Macros with Swift

Tags: dependency-injection, swift, ios8, xcode6

i'm trying to get the Objection Framework working with Swift (XCode 6.4).
Everything works pretty well beside the macros required for register/inject objects e.g. `objection_register`

I followed the approach from "[Bridging Cocoalumerjack with Swift](http://thehustudio.com/taste-of-ios-bridging-cocoalumberjack-for-swift/)" to get the macros working with Swift but XCode always complain: `Use of undeclared identifier 'initialize'` when implementing `objectionRegister` function in `ObjectionSwift.m`. Since i'm not to familiar with objective-c i got stuck when looking at the [Objection.h](https://github.com/atomicobject/objection/blob/develop/Source/Objection.h) initializer methods and trying to figure out whats wrong

Thx for your help!

**ObjectionSwift.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ObjectionSwift : NSObject
+ (void) objectionRegister(NSString *) name;
#endif
```

**ObjectionSwift.m**

```
#import "ObjectionSwift.h"
#import "Objection.h"

@implementation ObjectionSwift
+ (void) objectionRegister:(NSString *) name {
        objection_register_singleton(name)
}
@end
```

**UPDATE**
I switched to Typhoon as DI Framework which provides Swift support an works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class variable:

```
class ListingsViewController: UIViewController
{
    class var initialize: Bool
    {
        JSObjection.registerClass(ListingsViewController.self, scope: JSObjectionScopeNormal)

        return true
    }
}
```